# Cordova-sqlite-storage:why it add 'SELECT 1' before each sql?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I build a `Ionic` app which use `Ionic's` [SqlitePlugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database).
When I call `execSql` method,I found that it add a `SELECT 1` sql before my sql.

log is below:

```
codova:SQLitePlugin.backgroundExecuteSqlBatch:[{"dbargs":{"dbname":"appdb"},"executes":[{"qid":null,"sql":"SELECT 1","params":[]},{"qid":null,"sql":"select * from [abcde] where k1 = ? ","params":["六块"]}]}]
```

I looked it's code,

```
SQLitePluginTransaction = function(db, fn, error, success, txlock, readOnly) {
if (typeof fn !== "function") {

  /*
  This is consistent with the implementation in Chrome -- it
  throws if you pass anything other than a function. This also
  prevents us from stalling our txQueue if somebody passes a
  false value for fn.
   */
  throw newSQLError("transaction expected a function");
}
this.db = db;
this.fn = fn;
this.error = error;
this.success = success;
this.txlock = txlock;
this.readOnly = readOnly;
this.executes = [];
if (txlock) {
  this.addStatement("BEGIN", [], null, function(tx, err) {
    throw newSQLError("unable to begin transaction: " + err.message, err.code);
  });
} else {
  this.addStatement("SELECT 1", [], null, null);
}
```

It sames that it add `SELECT 1` when  `txlock` is false.  `txlock` is false when I call `executeSql` and is true when I call `sqlBatch`.

Why add `SELECT ONE`?